# MSSQL Logon Error in /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Hello I checked in /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog. then I get an error message like this:

> The login packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has bee
> 2021-01-22 16: 47: 38.21 Logon Error: 17832, Severity: 20, State: 2

[image: errorlog]

this happens every day.
I've done a search on the web search but I can't find the answer.
I only get the answer for Windows users. here is the link [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-authentication-problems-if-user-belongs-to-groups).

Hopefully I can find the answer here. thanks

Comment: FYI, the error you have won't be "the connect has bee", they'll be more text you haven't copied; I doubt the connection has *any* bees. 

Comment: A Google search for "Error: 17832, Severity: 20, State: 2" returns all of four results, all of them involving some kind of dodgy network appliance. Is there some kind of dodgy network appliance sitting between SQL Server and your client that's messing up the connections?

Answer (score 1):

> The login packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has

SQL Server listens on a TCP/IP port and expects clients who connect to use the [TDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec) network protocol.  If a client connects and sends data that doesn't conform to the TDS protocol, you'll get an error like this.  Could be a port scanner (possibly malicious), or some client trying to connect to SQL Server using FTP, Telnet, HTTP or some other TCP/IP-based network protocol that SQL Server doesn't use.